# C++ "No overloaded function takes 0 arguments" error

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a program that is saving a username, and the read username function of it keeps giving this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2661   'std::basic_ifstream>::open': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments  ConsoleApplication3 c:\users\main\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp 25

I am very new to C++ and don't understand what this error means, but I have my code here.

```
string name2()
{
    string name2;
    ifstream myfile("Userlog.txt");
    myfile.open();
    myfile >> name2;
    myfile.close();
    return name2;
}
```

Comment: `open()` takes at least one argument (the filename usually), you don't need `open()` here since you've passed a filename into the constructor.

Comment: So take out the open() command?

Comment: Ok yeah that worked thanks a ton I've been stuck on this for like 2 days, and just worked on other parts so it's good to get this done :D

Comment: BTW, if the user name has a space you'll need to use `std::getline(myfile, name2);`.

Comment: Yeah i said no spaces in the cout , but thanks for telling me how I could have them @Ken Y-N

Comment: I'm going to be an <expletive deleted> here. Next time rather than burning  2 days and working around a trivial problem, pop "ifstream open" or whatever the next function that gives you grief into the web search engine of your choice and take a quick read of the documentation.

Comment: When you have a problem with a standard function, it is always a good idea to read help or search the web. In fact, searching for `ifstream` on Google, you can have useful information in less than 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string name2;
ifstream myfile("Userlog.txt"); // here you are calling open
myfile.open(); // no version of ifstream. so open what??!!!
```

the line above can be translated as:

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("Userlog.txt");
myfile >> name2;
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Oh so i have to add the keyword ifstream?

Comment: yes there is not an object of ifstream in file `fstream.h` like `cin` in `istream`so you declare one yourself

Comment: Ok, had to figure out how sorry xD @Raindrop7